# systemd dynamic (runtime) dependencies

Tags: systemd

In our embedded device we have a main app and several services. Both main app and services are managed by systemd.

The main app has a plugin system, its plugins may be enabled or disabled at runtime. Say we have `PluginA` and `PluginB`. Both these plugins require a service, let's call it `ServiceP`.

Now if we had just one plugin we would start `ServiceP` during load and stop the service during unload. But as we have two plugins and their lifetimes can overlap, we need some dynamic dependencies or reference counter:

```
PluginA loaded   --> start ServiceP
PluginB loaded   --> do nothing (already started by PluginA)
PluginA unloaded --> do nothing (still required by PluginB)
PluginB unloaded --> stop ServiceP
```

Is there a way how to do this with systemd?

I assume not, as systemd manages whole applications. So if we implement the reference counter ourselves, could we have something as this:

```
# case 1
App starts (don't start ServiceP, app didn't request it yet)
App says it needs ServiceP --> start ServiceP
App says it no longer needs ServiceP --> stop ServiceP

# case 2
App says it needs ServiceP --> start ServiceP
App stops/crashes --> stop ServiceP
...
```

I assume it would be quite easy to achieve this by adding/removing dependencies in unit files and reloading them. But when `App` crashes it would not stop `ServiceP`, so I need to perform a cleanup action in `ExecStopPost=`. This means calling `systemctl daemon-reload` from unit file, which does not seem right. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Are the plugins distinct systemd services themselves?

Comment: @jdizzle no, they are shared libraries loaded by the main application during runtime

Comment: can you run `systemctl start` from inside your application?